# spark-streaming-kafka-10 DSteam is not pulling anything from Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to use spark-streaming-kafka-0.10 to pull messages from a kafka topic(broker version 0.10). I have checked that messages are being produced and used a KafkaConsumer to pull them successfully. Now, when I try to use the spark streaming api, I am not getting anything. If I just use KafkaUtils.createRDD and specify some offset ranges manually it works. But when, I try to use createDirectStream, all the rdds are empty and when I check the partition offsets it simply reports that all partitions are 0. Here is what I tried:

```
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("kafkastream")
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(3))
 val topics = Array("my_topic")

 val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
   "bootstrap.servers" -> "hostname:6667"
   "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
   "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
   "group.id" -> "my_group",
   "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
   "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean)
 )

 val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
   ssc,
   PreferConsistent,
   Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
 )

 stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
   val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
   rdd.foreachPartition { iter =>
     val o: OffsetRange = offsetRanges(TaskContext.get.partitionId)
     println(s"${o.topic} ${o.partition} ${o.fromOffset} ${o.untilOffset}")
   }

   val rddCount = rdd.count()
   println("rdd count: ", rddCount)

   // stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
 }

 ssc.start()
 ssc.awaitTermination()
```

All partitions show offset ranges from 0 to 0 and all rdds are empty. I would like it to start from the beginning of a partition but also pick up everything that is being produced to it.

Comment: How do you `spark-submit` the app? How do you publish messages? Can you add it to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that it was a kafka-clients issue. I was using kafka-clients 0.10.1.1 and that had a bug, which was fixed here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4547

Thus, the fix for me was updating to 0.10.2.1. spark-streaming-kafka was using a compile dependency of 0.10.0.1, but I was overwriting it when I included my own version.